# Error connecting to ftp server through goftp

Tags: go, ftp, ftp-client

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server and upload a file for test. (I'm new to FTP as well as golang.)

Below is the code I'm using to Dial a connection and upload a file.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "time"

    "github.com/secsy/goftp"
)

var buildDate string

var server = "eg.server.com:port"
var user = "DMStage"
var pwd = "password"
var str1 = ""
var ftpServerPath = "/DmABM/"

func main() {

    config := goftp.Config{
        User:               user,
        Password:           pwd,
        ConnectionsPerHost: 10,
        Timeout:            10 * time.Second,
        Logger:             os.Stderr,
    }

    client, err := goftp.DialConfig(config, server)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Connection okay")

    // Upload a file from disk
    bigFile, err := os.Open("eg.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Read file from local")

    fmt.Println("Reading directory files")

    files, err := client.ReadDir(ftpServerPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file.Name())
    }

    fmt.Println("Trying to read the current directory")

    str1, err = client.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    println("Done reading dir")
    println(str1)

    err = client.Store("eg.txt", bigFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

But when I run the script, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\DUDE\Desktop\Sagemaker\Work\Projects\ABM\abm-master@ccbdb3d69fc\cmd\smb>go run main.go
Connection okay
Read file from local
Reading directory files
goftp: 0.002 #1 opening control connection to 159.x.x.x:990
goftp: 10.254 #1 error reading response: read tcp 10.158.y.y:64887->159.x.x.x:990: i/o timeout
goftp: 10.254 #1 closing
goftp: 10.255 #1 error connecting: error reading response: read tcp 10.158.y.y:64887->159.x.x.x:990: i/o timeout
panic: error reading response: read tcp 10.158.y.y:64887->159.x.x.x:990: i/o timeout

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        C:/Users/DUDE/Desktop/Sagemaker/Work/Projects/ABM/abm-master@ccbdb3d69fc/cmd/smb/main.go:61 +0x725
exit status 2
```

I'm behind a company firewall, could it be the firewall that's not allowing golang to dial tcp??
(FTP server is also part of the company network.)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FTP (being old) is known for its unusual approach to handling data transfer: normally, when a client initiates data transfer, _server_ connects to a client-specified socket (host:port). There's another mode, called "passive", when this is reversed, and the server tells the client where to connect. With firevalls, the normal, active, mode is most of the time prohibited outright for obvious reasons; passive mode _may_ work if the firewall supports it—it has to implement FTP dissection support (Linux does) and has the feature turned on.

Comment: …so, I'd first try with a native client (the`ftp` command-line tool can be installed even on Windows) and use it to try to connect—specifically after issuing the `pasv` command first. If it works, then work on improving your code so that it also uses passive mode; otherwise you're possibly out of luck—given the restrictions.

Comment: More info on FTP NAT traversal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#NAT_and_firewall_traversal

Comment: Would opening a raw connection work in this case? I'm not sure if a raw connection is the passive route.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning. Raw sockets allow crafting of almost arbitrary TCP packets but if you are to connect to a FTP server, no matter which way you generate your client packets, they _have to_ transport data of a FTP protocol session, so why even bother? I mean, it's like using raw sockets to perform an HTTP GET request: you can do that but what for—provided much more convenient ways to carry out this task do exist?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the whole FTP/ Networking world so don't have much experience with things (I was throwing out ideas). But thank you, I'll try the passive connection to see if that works.

Comment: Port 990 is FTP's TLS port, similar to port 443 for HTTPS.  Your Golang code does not appear to be ready for a TLS handshake on port 990; perhaps that might be why it is having trouble with the network IO to that port?

Comment: Should I enable TLS in my code? https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/secsy/goftp.
I looked into the documentation and there is a mention of TLS at the bottom, there are two moods mentioned: TLSImplicit and TLSExplicit. I'm not sure which one will be applicable here.

Comment: I tried enabling TLS in my golang script for both: TLSImplicit and TLSExplicit, it still showed the same i/o error. I'm wondering it could only be what @kostix mentioned, will try his way for now and update this request.

Comment: @kostix, So I tried doing the passive mode.

// Enable "active" FTP data connections where the server connects to the client to
 // establish data connections (does not work if client is behind NAT). If TLSConfig
 // is specified, it will be used when listening for active connections.
 ActiveTransfers bool
I made it false for a passive mode but still getting the same error.